# Undeletable EEPROM or other storage for micocontrollers?

Tags: memory, eeprom

Is there such thing as permanent EEPROM storage?

The data written should be un-deletable.

Once written it should be there as long as the chip is not destroyed or damaged.

Any other alternatives to EEPROMs are welcome.

I use DVD drives for PC. But I need a similar chip or system for microcontrollers.

Important: I don't want this to be implemented in my microcontroller Software by custom code. The Chip or IC or System it self should have that by default.

Link on Security.SE:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/128160/undeletable-logging-or-file-writing/128161#128161

Comment: The second "E" in "EEPROM" stands for "erasable", so whatever it is, it won't be called an EEPROM.

Comment: How much storage do you need?

Comment: As you are thinking about inside attacks and keylogging, it may be better to migrate this question to the Information Security SE board, where there are people far more expert in these topics.

Comment: EPROM (without the "EE" for Electrically Erasable". Technically it is still erasable, but you need to shine an UV light on it for several minutes or more. And that's difficult in an OTP EPROM because there is no window in the package... Programming requires high voltage (12 or 13.5 in "newer" ones, up to 21 or 28V in really old ones)

Comment: @Neil_UK This is relevant to this site because I want a hardware. I don't want the programming part. I just want a i2c or SPI device that is undeletable. The manufacturer should have implemented that function in the chip.

Comment: Many microcontrollers have OTP versions, just look at the available options for you favorite part or vendor.

Comment: @BrianDrummond You can still trash the data on a OTP (windowless) EROM, as I think about it (was my first thought, too) - they start out full of 1's (IIRC - does not matter if it's 0's and my memory sucks) and you program by flipping the bits you want the other way. To trash them (rather than reprogram them) you'd just flip all the bits that hadn't been flipped in programming them.

Comment: @Ecnerwal yes that is true, you can overwrite '1's with '0's but you cannot delete (erase back to '1'). So if there is requirement is to avoid malicious tampering, you would have to protect records, perhaps by taking pairs of bits (01 = 1, 10 = 0). Then 11 = unwritten and 00 = evidence of tampering, for example.

Answer (score 5):

Yes -- what you are after exists, at least for small sizes.  While most OTP EPROMs are parallel devices designed to be "burned" in dedicated EPROM programming hardware, Maxim makes exactly the part you're after in the form of the [DS2505](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/digital/memory-products/DS2505.html) -- 16kbits of in-system programmable OTP EPROM, with a unique serial number lasered into the chip as well that can be used to thwart chip replacement attacks.

You'll need a wee bit of drive circuitry as well as some bit-banging code to talk 1-Wire as the DS2505 requires its Vpp pulse to be muxed onto the 1-Wire interface along with normal power and data.

Comment: The serial number would presumably prevent copying partial or modified data into another DS2505 and passing it off as the original to someone who can then examine the hardware.  But I'm not seeing any feature in the DS2505 summary which would rule out substitution of an MCU programmed to emulate the original DS2505 including serial number to the confusion of someone who can only then examine the system through software.  So this only seems to provide protection in the case where the hardware can be examined for substitution... and there may be MCUs in similar enough (or custom?) packages...

Comment: @ChrisStratton -- you'd need to do an awful lot of work to emulate the DS2505 with a MCU considering it's a) a 1-wire device and b) takes 12V Vpp pulses multiplexed onto that 1-wire interface.

Comment: You mean like a resistor and a zener diode, and maybe a capacitor?  Of course the result is not unlike someone copying and replacing the DVD in the poster's desktop setup.

Comment: @ChrisStratton -- that takes care of b) but leaves a) -- you'd need to do more work still to get a) going (you *might* be able to pull it off by abusing the ESD diodes on the micro as rectifiers -- but good luck getting all that past even a cursory visual inspection of the insides -- neither the TSOC-6 (tiny SMT) nor the TO-92 (...when was the last time you met a micro in TO-92?) would lend itself well to this attack in the way say a DIP would)

Comment: Black epoxy should not be hard to source.  Used older wire bond machines aren't that expensive.  It all depends on what your concern is.  The irony is that the more the original is covered in gunk, the easier it is to disguise a substitution.

Comment: @ChrisStratton -- agreed on not covering the original in gunk -- TO-92s are pretty distinctively shaped critters, no?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I generally use Handwriting foe DVDs. Maybe I could use a marker to write on the epoxy.

Answer (score 2):

One of your comments suggests it has to be resistant to an 'inside attack'. Which will be difficult.

What do you actually want to achieve?

a) 100% reliable access to your data? If so, a denial of service attack, damage of the data or the chip would be a lose for you.

b) 100% reliable trust in the veracity of your data, so no alteration without detection? As you mention data valid until damaged in your OP, this could be sufficient, depending on whether 'destroyed' means the physical chip (or system it's embedded in) or the data on it.

If a) then you have an insurmountable problem if the attacker has physical access to the system. If he can zap the chip, or the system, or hit it with a hammer, really all bets are off if he has access.

If b) then you don't need any physical controls at all. A sufficiently strong cryptographic checksum stored with the data will tell you whether it has been altered in any way since writing.

So OTP and write bits are neither necessary (for b) nor sufficient (for a). Make sure you pick a solution that meets your real needs, and understand what you really need.

Comment: I have no solution for DOS. I need to know if the data has been altered. Cryptography is not an option as the attacker may be a police state keylogging everything the user types. I need b) with hardware not software as software can be backdoored.

Comment: I need both hardware and software with b) if possible. Hardware is mandatory.

Comment: If you have been keylogged, then all bets are off. Kiss your security, and the thing you sit on, goodbye.

Comment: That is why I use storage like DVD/CD discs for PC. I need logging for Microcontrollers now. I don't want security through obscurity. I want Hardware level security.

Comment: The level of discourse you're providing suggests you're out of your depth here...

Comment: @Wally How does keylogging relate to your question in any way? How does keylogging interfere with your system's ability to use digital signatures?

Comment: @JimmyB I don't want to include security through obscurity through code in the Microcontroller. The code on my Micro should be OpenSource. I need a chip that's made to be un-deletable by the manufacturer itself.

Comment: @Wally Digital signatures are absolutely not "security through obscurity". OpenPGP is open source, but not insecure. Of course, every instance of your implementation will have to generate and use its own public/private key pair, but the code itself is the same. You could generate the key pair on your PC before delivery of the device, or even have the µC generate the keys itself. In the latter case, the µC will only ever output the *public* key when required, but the private key will be inaccessible without physically breaking the µC; so there's no way anybody could generate a valid signature

Comment: except for the µC itself. This way, you can tell for sure if the data recorded is genuine and unaltered at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called a ROM, read only memory. A One Time Programmable (OTP) ROM is what you want. Alternatively an EEPROM with a Write Protection or Write enable pin that you can tie to VCC or GND to prevent rewriting. It's a less than 100% solution, if you have physical access, though you could just pour epoxy or potting compound over the EEPROM afterwards to make it really hard to write enable.

Comment: There are issues about how long memory chips can retain data, and nothing beats the old 'platinum fuse' IC's, but I think ROM's so far have better data retention, with large memory cells and a long track record. EEPROMS have a quoted but unproven long life.

Comment: I need it be un-deletable from an inside attack perspective. So, write enable pin is not an option. I'll have to look into epoxy.

Comment: @wally which is why I recommend the epoxy solution. If this is a one off and you have an EEPROM already, it's simple.  If this is for production a OTP ROM is better. But even ROM arnt 100%. Only about 99%. Proof. They could always glitch it, or replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Other people have asked you to cover your ground rules already, so we know that whatever you put on can be damaged or removed if the aggressor has access to the components.

I don't know how much ROM data you need. But looking at what can be programmable by you and then stay 'tamper-proof', I'd suggest using a Lattice iCE40 FPGA such as an iCE40LP1K. It contains OTP configuration Flash, so you alone can programme it but no-one can read it or reprogramme it.

As per p6 of Lattice TN1248 'iCE40 Programming And Configuration':

"The NVCM contents are entirely contained within the iCE40 device and are not readable once protected by the one-time programmable Security bits. Furthermore, there is no observable difference between a programmed or un-programmed memory cell using optical or electron microscopy. The NVCM memory has a programming interface similar to a 25-series SPI serial Flash PROM. Consequently, it can be programmed using Diamond Programmer (version 2.2 or later) before or after circuit board assembly or programmed in-system from a microprocessor or other intelligent controller."

You then design an FPGA circuit to implement a ROM of your data and your communications port. That circuit is then loaded into the FPGA configuration from the internal OTP memory.

Your ROM communications port protocol is of your choice. It can be to a standard (e.g. SPI, I2C) or a made-up one that's difficult to understand by an intruder with a 'scope. I appreciate that obfuscation of data will not save you in your application but it will slow those intruders down a bit and its a cheap option.

Which device you need and whether an iCE40 can hold all your data depends how much you've got and I don't know that. Oh, and I think the iCE40 also has an internal oscillator but I'd need to check that.

Putting a conformal coating on to make it very difficult to observe pin activity seems a cheap option afterwards, if its of use. You can either have it done professionally or get medieval with a packet of Araldite.

Answer (score 0):

Some chips have OTP areas that are for serialization information etc. It depends on the manufacturer and product line as to whether that is available on-chip though.

But EEPROM can be 'permanent' if you write your program so that it can't be overwritten!